# MxArray is not a Point in mexopencv

Tags: c++, matlab, computer-vision

Can any one help me with that error , I am trying to find fundamental matrix of two images using mexopencv library in matlab , this is my code

```
    global fmImage1;
    global fmImage2;
    %-------------Read First Image---------------------------------
     [filename pathname]=uigetfile({'*.jpg'},'File Selector',...
        'C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures');
    if isequal(filename,0) | isequal(pathname,0);
        return; end %Pressed Cancel
    imagePath=strcat(pathname,filename);

    fmImage1=imread(imagePath);
    figure,
    imshow(fmImage1);

     %-------------Read Scond Image---------------------------------
     [filename pathname]=uigetfile({'*.jpg'},'File Selector',...
        'C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures');
    if isequal(filename,0) | isequal(pathname,0);
        return; end %Pressed Cancel
    imagePath=strcat(pathname,filename);

    fmImage2=imread(imagePath);
    figure,
    imshow(fmImage2);
 %---------------------------------------------------------------------
 %*********************************************************************

    %detect features keypoints from both images
    keypoints_1 = cv.SIFT(fmImage1);
    keypoints_2 = cv.SIFT(fmImage2);
    %convert keypoints to cell array of n points so that I can use them in findFM
    l1=length(keypoints_1);
    l2=length(keypoints_2);
    if l1>l2
        Lth=l2;
    else
        Lth=l1;
    end
    points1_cell=cell(1,20);
    points2_cell=cell(1,20);

    for i=1:20
        point1_x=round(keypoints_1(i).pt (1));
        point1_y=round(keypoints_2(i).pt (2));
        %image2
        point2_x=round(keypoints_1(i).pt (1));
        point2_y=round(keypoints_2(i).pt (2));

        points1_cell{i}={[point1_x,point1_y]};
        points2_cell{i}={[point2_x,point2_y]};

    end
    % 8 points  try



   [F,mask] = cv.findFundamentalMat(points1_cell,points2_cell);
```

Now this I got this error 
??? Error using ==> findFundamentalMat
MxArray is not a Point

Error in ==> drawEpipolarLineTest at 56
       F = cv.findFundamentalMat(points1_cell,points2_cell);

****************************************************************8
In mexopencv documentation for findFundamentalMat http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~kyamagu/mexopencv/matlab/findFundamentalMat.html
The input is a cell arrays for n element ,I can't figure what is the problem with my code

Comment: You can try using the `estimateFundamentalMatrix` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.

Comment: I do not have computer vision toolbox in matlab so I am using this package mexopencv